# copy & paste back into filtered list in excel

Tags: excel, list, filter

i have a huge excel sheet with 13k rows and 8 columns.
i have been looking for a way to paste back into the visible rows on the filtered list.
i even got a code from mr.excel video [mr. excel podcast](http://www.mrexcel.com/podcast977.html)

```
        Sub PasteBack()
    ' Assumes the Filtered Sheet1 is active
    Set DataToCopy = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    n = 2 ' index for range to copy from Sheet2 one row at a time, skipping headers
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' row 1 is header
        If Not Rows(i).Hidden Then
            DataToCopy.Offset(n - 1).Resize(1).Copy Cells(i, 1)
            n = n + 1
            If n > DataToCopy.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

the problem with this code is that excel becomes unresponsive if the data is alot. it works perfect if the data is less. 
can someone help me paste back data into a filtered list

Comment: + plus one for the fact that you think 13K rows × 8 columns is 'huge'.  :)

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are working with a filtered list at all. Do you mean that each cell simply has to be tested for the existence of a space character before the method of string insertion/concatenation is determined?

Comment: well 13k x 8 rows x 8 sheets is...

Comment: extremely sorry for pasting the wrong code. that code was for merging the content of one cell into another cell containing a text string.
corrected the code now.
@jeeped sorry

Comment: Too many unanswered questions to proceed. Top of the list: a) what is the filter? b) what is the sort order? c) what do you want to do with the extra rows if there are more than what can be copied across from Sheet2? d) How many rows in a typical data transfer? e) what would be the maximum rows in a data transfer?

Comment: a)filter is being used to show only a the rows required. filtering based on tax, name and many other criteria. b) there is no sort order. its just that the the rows remain in the same order they have been entered. c)sheet2 would never have extra rows, in my case. but you can always add the extra rows at the bottom of sheet1. d)my current sheet2 has around 6k rows to be transferred into sheet1 which has 13k rows, but after filtering sheet1, the no. of rows on both sheet1 and sheet2 are same. e)cant acertain the maximum rows, as i guess i would even need to deal with around 15k rows next

Answer (score 1):

Processing the string criteria checks and string parsing routines in a variant array that was both populated and returned to the worksheet *en masse* should significantly speed things up.

```
Sub MergeCols()
    Dim cell As Range, pos As Long
    Dim vSTRs As Variant, v As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")   '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
            vSTRs = .Value2
            For v = LBound(vSTRs, 1) To UBound(vSTRs, 1)
                If CBool(InStr(1, vSTRs(v, 1), Chr(32))) Then
                    pos = InStrRev(vSTRs(v, 1), Chr(32))
                    vSTRs(v, 1) = Join(Array(Left(vSTRs(v, 1), pos - 1), vSTRs(v, 2), _
                                        Mid(vSTRs(v, 1), pos + 1)), Chr(32))
                ElseIf CBool(Len(Trim(vSTRs(v, 1)))) Then
                    vSTRs(v, 1) = Join(Array(vSTRs(v, 1), vSTRs(v, 2)), Chr(32))
                End If
            Next v
            .Columns(1) = Application.Index(vSTRs, 0, 1)
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I added the condition not to process if there was a blank in column B. Your original did not require this as it was defining the scope of the operation from the top of column B down. My routine defines the scope as being from B2 to the bottom of column C (as seen from the bottom looking up).

Comment: sorry for pasting the wrong code last night, was working late and was too sleepy. 
i just corrected the code i got from mr.excels podcast. i hope you can look into it once again

Comment: can you please look into this

Answer (score 0):

well this is a very general question and lots of people have been facing this issue, when i searched on google. but i was not able to find a perfect solution.

```
p.code  product_name  packing  price  tax   manufacturer
abc12   shampoo       100ml    49     5     abc pvt ltd
xyz98   powder        50gm     30     14.5  xyz pvt ltd
fdc321  conditioner   75ml     90     14.5  fdc
abc21   oil           100ml    49     5     abc pvt ltd
```

i have just put down a few columns and rows. but there would be alot more.
now when i filter the columns with respect to tax and show only 5% tax items (or any other filter criteria).

and i copy the entries to another sheet for editing. when i try to paste it back into the filtered list, the entries dont get pasted into the visible filtered rows. instead they get pasted even on the non-visible rows which are hidden by the filter.

i am looking for a way to paste back the data from a different sheet

sheet1 has complete data

sheet2 has data extracted from sheet1

both sheets have same columns and order as sheet2's data is extracted from sheet1's data using a filter criteria.

but when i would be pasting back the data, sheet1's data would be filtered with the same criteria, which was used to extract data for sheet2. so the no. of visible rows in sheet1 would be equal to total no. of rows in sheet2.

i hope this explains the situation. if there is still some confusion you could take a look at this  [Video demonstrating the problem](https://youtu.be/5dMEejhLv74)